# Error: request aborted at IncomingMessage.onAborted

Tags: json, node.js, post, body-parser

This error appears when ./insert post function is called. 
I think that reason is

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

How can I solve this problem?

```
Error: request aborted
at IncomingMessage.onAborted (C:\nodejs\node_modules\body-parser\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:269:10)
at emitNone (events.js:67:13)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:166:7)
at abortIncoming (_http_server.js:280:11)
at Socket.serverSocketCloseListener (_http_server.js:293:5)
at emitOne (events.js:82:20)
at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
at TCP._onclose (net.js:469:12)
```

**test.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var connect_router = require('connect_router');
var url = require('url');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var fs = require('fs');
var ejs = require('ejs');
var bodyParser= require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
   host: 'localhost',
   user: 'root',
   password: 'password',
   database :'test'
});


app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send('hello world'+ Date.now()+"!!");
});

var member;

app.get('/start', function(req, res){

    connection.query('select * from member;',function(err, data){

    console.log(data);

    res.status(200).json({member: data});
    });

});

app.post('/insert',function(req, res, err){

  console.log('insert');

  var body= req.body;


 console.log(body);
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-type':'application/json'});

  connection.query('INSERT INTO member values('+body.id+','+body.password+','+body.paypal+')', function(err,res){
      if(err) throw err;

  });
});

var server = app.listen(2000, function(){
  console.log("Express server is started (port :2000)")
});
```

Answer (score 2):

**First.** Your query is incorrect:

```
connection.query('INSERT INTO member values('+body.id+','+body.password+','+body.paypal+')', function(err,res){
              if(err) throw err;

       })
```

You need to add quotes to the values to make the query look something like this:

```
INSERT INTO member values('+body.id+',"'+body.password+'","'+body.paypal+'")
```

**Second.** You do not seem to be sending a response back to the browser.

**Third.** You should not build queries using concatenation because you're vulnerable to SQL injections.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the problem is in: stream-utils/raw-body#57
Because you globalise bodyParser.json in `app.use(bodyParser.json());`
Anyways it's a good practice to have bodyParser.json() globalised... it should be supported

for me it solved:

```
let json = require('body-parser').json();
json.unless = require('express-unless');
let middleware = [
    json.unless({ path: /\/webhooks*/ })
    /** //
]
```

Answer (score 0):

as ernest says here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63989854/12500034

this issue is related to the body-parser package setup

```
// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.use(function (req, res) {
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain')
  res.write('you posted:\n')
  res.end(JSON.stringify(req.body, null, 2))
})
```

here is a link for more details [adding a generic JSON and URL-encoded parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#expressconnect-top-level-generic)

Answer (score 0):

If you use vue+axios framework, with this Error, or you send a post request to the server (all method but post method doesn't work), then has nothing happened, you can check your `vue.config.js`
here is one line code in this file:

> before: require('./mock/mock-server.js')

If you comment out this line, then it's OK for your project, because this file has added a midware in the request, cause Node.js server midware couldn't find correct params, because when cross a midware process then the next router only get an empty body:{}